# Неблокирующее чтение данных из tcp соединения

Tags: golang

Пишу tcp сервер. Он рассчитан на большое количество соединений из которых надо одновременно читать данные. Обработка этих соединений выглядит примерно так:

```
for {
    for _, conn := range connections {
        buf := make([]byte, 4096)
        _, err := conn.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что `conn.Read` блочит весь код и не позволяет ему выполняться до того момента пока этот пользователь не отправит чего-либо. Могу ли я как-то проверить, что пришли какие-то данные и только в этом случае прочитать? Конечно я могу сделать много горутин. Но их будет много тысяч и память очень быстро кончится

Comment: Я бы, конечно, делал на горутинах. Память не может кончиться - максимальное число открытых сокетов 64 тысячи, размер стека для горутины порядка 10 кб. Накинем ещё на накладные расходы - получится максимум 1 Гб. По нынешним временам это не то, о чем следует беспокоиться. Если же вы, тем не менее, хотите сэкономить память, то надо писать как на Си - [`select`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Select), [`read`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Read) и прочие `sendto`.

Comment: conn.Read - блокирующая операция. без горутин - никак. на любом языке чтение будет блокирующим

Comment: @PakUula Как это вы 64 тысячи насчитали? Можно куда больше 64 тысяч сделать

Comment: @SeniorPomidor не на любом и без горутин можно. Если заглянуть в исходный код `conn.Read` то окажется что там есть проверка на наличие данных и если данных нет то вызывается метод `wait` или как он там называется. Так вот я бы хотел чтобы этот метод не вызывался, а мне возвращался пустой ответ. Но этого я достигну только переписыванием пакета tcp чего я не хочу. В интернете есть решения с реализациями `netpool` в go где это переписано. Но я думал есть более простые решения

Answer (score 1):

Про 64к я, конечно не прав.

Но всё равно делал бы на горутинах. Память нынче стоит копейки. Скажем, 16-ядерный сервер с 32 гб памяти можно арендовать в Амазоне за 0.4 доллара в час. То есть в месяц порядка $300

Почему это копейки? Потому что при большой нагрузке основные деньги придётся платить за трафик.

Предположим, ваш сервер обслуживает 100 тыс одновременных соединений. 32 гб памяти будет вполне достаточно, чтобы обработать их горутинами.

Пусть это будет онлайн игрушка с небольшим постоянным трафиком. Скажем, по килобайту в секунду. Тогда месячный трафик такого сервера составит 2.6 петабайта, за которые амазон захочет **от** 50 **ТЫСЯЧ** долларов. У них тариф по США 0.02 USD за Гб, по миру 0.09 USD за Гб.

Конечно, можно найти хостинги с более гуманной тарификацией. И тем не менее, месячная оплата за трафик будет тысячи долларов, а за виртуалку - полторы-две сотни.

Так что нет смысла экономить память, ИМХО.

Comment: Очень много провайдеров которые предлагают безлимитный трафик =) 100к соединений для одного сервера это мало, можно больше. Нашёл такую статью, думаю буду использовать их решение с 3 миллионами соединений: https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/331784/ Конечно очень маловероятно что сейчас будет такой трафик, но задел на будущее всегда хорошо

Comment: И я вообще не вижу смысла использовать amazon. Тот же reg.ru предлагает те же 16 ядер, 32 потока и уже 64гб памяти за 150 долларов и туда же входит безлимитный трафик.

Comment: @Inventor конечно, amazon здесь только для примера. Я сам им перестал пользоваться после того, как увидел ценник за трафик. Сейчас мои серваки бегают на хостинге с включенным 4 тб трафика. Но у вас же петабайты!

Comment: @Inventor Думаю, нужно читать мелким шрифтом :) У того же reg.ru трафик вроде безлимитный, но ... Клиент платит за ширину канала. Скажем, за гигабитную полосу [они просят 46 тыр в месяц, а за десятигигабитную 350 тыр в месяц](https://www.reg.ru/dedicated/server_details/51354#expanders=network). Но трафик типа безлимитный, да )

Comment: Стандартная ширина там 100мбит, я думаю этого вполне хватит, потому что 1 запрос в среднем будет 1кб или примерно 12к запросов одновременно. Те 3млн о которых я говорю это вебсокеты, которые просто висят пока пользователь просматривает какую-либо страницу, а у 80% скорее всего будет просто открыта вкладка в браузере, которой они не пользуются. И я очень сомневаюсь что на старте количество всех соединений дойдёт хотя бы до тех же 10к, не говоря о одновременных запросах =)

Comment: @Inventor в комментарии к статье упомянули, что расход ресурсов '60Кбайт на соединение' до оптимизации. Поэтому сервер на 32 Гб  "в лоб" потянет полмиллиона одновременных соединений. В любом случае, удачи вам в вашем проекте!